# styling the browser generated rollovers for svg title tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the appearance of the attached screenshot, the yellow rollover box where it says : Google Search: 90.

[image]

This is generated from an svg title element, like so:

```
<g class="leaf node" transform="translate(494.3930607245582,316.76111782506564)">
  <title>Youtube: 60</title>
  <circle r="19.117124489931257"></circle>
  <text dy=".3em" style="text-anchor: middle;">Youtub</text>
</g>
```

I'm generating these through the library [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), and I have things like jquery at my disposal, if it's helpful.

Comment: You can create a tootip using html elements and toggle it when mouse in/out with or without a timeout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yellow popup box is a tooltip box, the default background color is decided by system.
If you are using jquery, please refer to http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip to checkout tooltip plugin. You may customize the tooltip.